# Should this compile?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-bug

I have the following code:

```
#include "type_traits"

template<typename T_>
struct thing{
    template<typename me_type>
    struct inner { 
        static T_& impl_0 (void* me ) { return static_cast<me_type*>(me )->operator*(); } 

        static auto getThing()
        {
            return std::integral_constant<T_& (*)(void*),&impl_0>();
        }
    };
};
```

It declares a static function inside a templated class that is inside another templated class.

Then it declares an auto function, which returns an pointer to that function, but first it puts it into a `std::integral_constant`

When I give this to gcc version 7.3 ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/WPX6dH)) with the compiler flags `-std=c++14` it complains:

```
<source>: In static member function 'static auto thing<T_>::inner<me_type>::getThing()':
<source>:11:69: error: template argument 2 is invalid
                 return std::integral_constant<T_& (*)(void*),&impl_0>();
```

But when I give it to clang version 6.0.0 it compiles just fine ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/fSgztX)).

Should it compile or not?

Comment: If I give it to gcc with `-std=c++17`, it compiles. It also compiles with gcc trunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it should compile as is, because function name should be visible. However, that fixes it:

```
    struct inner { 
        static auto getThing()
        {
            return std::integral_constant<T_& (*)(void*),&inner::impl_0>();
        }
    };
```